# Is it possible to connect PayPal with Parse.com for iOS app?

Tags: ios, paypal, parse-platform

hello I'm making a iOS app where i need to process payments so that a seller can receive payments from a buyer.

So i thought PayPal would be a good option as i saw another app (Depop) has this feature.

I want the experience to be all in app.
I saw somewhere that i need to have my own server? Which i dont know how to do. so if that is the case, how can i get started on that.

Or i was thinking of using Stripe instead?

I just need to know how i can implement it in my iOS app so that a buyer can pay the seller directly.

Comment: What are you selling? Do you need to use in-app purchase for it?

Comment: im not selling anything, a company would use my app to sell there physical product like a shirt, and a buyer can use the app to purchase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't implement it in your app as such, you would implement it in cloud code ([using this parse guide](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-with-third-party-services)) and the server would do all the hard work of making and verifying the purchase and releasing the goods. The app just needs to deal with login and token management and that would be done either with a web view or a provided SDK from the payment vendor.

If you're using parse then it is your server.

Comment: do you think it would be better to use Stripe because it has a Cloud Module already for Parse?
https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#stripe

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much always easier to use existing code than to write from scratch...